# Asynchronous problems in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am learning C# and in order to train, I would like to make a PowerPoint addin asking questions.
The addin (a panel on a side) :

- prints questions like "how many grammes are there in 1.3kg ?"
- waits the answer of the user in a textbox in the addin (BUT does not block entire PowerPoint UI)

and depending on the answer:

- displays congrat and changes question themes (for example "what is the speed if you drive 90km in 1h30 ?")
- displays explanation on the slide and continues questions on this theme (for example "convert 25000g in kg ?")

I have a problem managing asynchronous aspects. I am also working on a graphic context with a UI, so what I have understood is it can be more complicated as there is only 1 thread in that case.

With the following code, my UI is completely locked when I click the startButton. Could you explain me why it locks and what I should change to attend the behavior I expect ?

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null; // used with answer text box to say the box is filled

//event handlers
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Trigger();
}

private void answerTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    tcs.TrySetResult(true); //signal to say it's OK, answer is available
}

private async void Trigger()
{
    await QuestionManager();
}

private async Task QuestionManager()
{
    // questions and answers
    string qt1 = "how many grammes are there in 1.3 kg ?";
    string ans1 = "1300";
    string qt1b = "convert 25000g in kg ?";
    string ans1b = "25";
    string qt2 = "what is the speed (in km/h) if you drive 90km in 1h30 ?";
    string ans2 = "60";

    string answer = qt1;
    string question ="";

    //manage which answer should be asked
    while (answer != "stop")
    {
        if (question == qt1)
        {
            if (answer == ans1)
                question = qt2;
            else
                question = qt1b;
        }
        if (question == qt1b)
        {
            if (answer == ans1b)
                question = qt2;
            else
                question = "end";
        }
        if (question == qt2)
        {
            if (answer == ans2)
                question = "end";
            else
                question = "end";
        }
        answer = MyQuestion(question).Result;
        tcs.TrySetResult(false);
    }
}

private async Task<string> MyQuestion(string question)
{
    computerQuestionLabel.Text = question; // displays question on the user interface
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    await tcs.Task;
    if (question == "end")
        return "stop";
    else
        return answerTextBox.Text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: **Why Powerpoint?**

Comment: It is just to train. I have seen addin in PowerPoint, that I didn't know and it interested me to try to make one.I agree, asking scholar questions in a PowerPoint addin is a little bit strange, but it is a good occasion to test if I master asynchronous parts (with my problems, obviously I dont')

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll write an answer for this then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the issue: `answer = MyQuestion(question).Result;`.

Using `Result` on a `Task` means "get me the result, but if it's not yet available, *wait* - ie block the thread waiting for the result of this".

Since `MyQuestion` waits for the `Task` from a `TaskCompletionSource` that `QuestionManager` or other UI code is supposed to complete, and `QuestionManager` (through `Result`) is waiting for `MyQuestion` to finish, you have a deadlock! `QuestionManager` is blocking the UI thread, so `tcs` can't receive a result either through the next line or through any other UI code running.

Change `Result` to `await`ing it, and this will go away. I am not certain that the rest of the logic will hold together, but this is the answer to why the UI locks up when you run the code you posted.

---

As for how to solve this: none of this actually requires any asynchronous waiting. Using asynchrony obscures the code you actually want to write, and you're using `async void` methods [which is nearly always a bad idea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

What I would do is have a class with properties for a question and an answer, keep a list of all remaining questions-and-answers and always work against the first item in that list whenever a new answer is submitted to see if the answer is correct - you'll know whether to show "wrong answer" and have them try again or whether to advance to the next question.

For example:

```
class QuestionAndAnswer {
    public string Question { get; set; } 
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

private List<QuestionAndAnswer> _currentQuestions; // create this list when loading everything

private int _currentQuestionIndex = 0; // points to which element/index in the list contains the question shown on screen

// call this once after you have loaded _currentQuestions with your data
public void ShowCurrentQuestion() { 
    var currQuestion = _currentQuestion[_currentQuestionIndex];
    computerQuestionLabel.Text = currQuestion.Question;
    answerTextBox.Text = "";
}

// call this from whichever event handler means that the user has
// submitted an answer - an Answer button's Click event, maybe
// answerTextBox's KeyPress event or something else.
public void CheckForAnswer() {
    var currentAnswer = answerTextBox.Text;
    var currQuestion = _currentQuestion[_currentQuestionIndex];
    if (currQuestion.Answer == currentAnswer) { // correct
        var nextQuestionIndex = _currentQuestionIndex + 1;
        if (nextQuestionIndex == _currentQuestion.Count) { 
            // all questions answered! do the appropriate thing
        } else {
            // still questions left, show the next one
            _currentQuestionIndex = nextQuestionIndex;
            ShowCurrentQuestion();
        }
    } else {
        // wrong answer; the question that needs to be shown is 
        // already shown, you can handle "stop" or other things here
    }
}
```

There's a natural event here meaning "someone just submitted a new answer", and you can use that as a funnel point. There's no need to write code that waits for new answers. By writing code that makes things happen in response to user events, you are already in effect doing things asynchronously (do your stuff, wait for the user to do something, do even more stuff), it's just that you're not using `async`/`await`/`Task`s or writing explicitly asynchronous code to do it.

Comment: Totally agree with *"none of this actually requires any asynchronous waiting"*, but since *"It is just to train."* I guess it's ok `+1`

Comment: True it is to train, but if I have not chosen the right solution, it is not a good practice to keep. But I have not understood well the solution your propose: you make a class for questions/answers - but you have to wait the event "new answer submitted" anyway, no ?

Comment: @droledenom: You have a user interface - you already know when the new answer is submitted! Exactly when is up for you to define -
 when a button labelled "Answer" is clicked, when text has been entered into a text box and tabbed away from, etc. I think it corresponds to the `//signal to say it's OK, answer is available` comment in your code, even if it illustrates how complicated the current solution is since it has to run a whole lot of logic again every time that happens. Every key press is a new TaskCompletionSource, since it can only be completed *once*.

Comment: I didn't mean that the class would have a literal event meaning that, I meant the event handler, whichever it is, that already in your UI code signals that a new answer has been submitted.

Comment: @Jesper You make a question/answer class and there is an event handler "new answer submitted". What will you do in the event handler ? You create a new instance of the class, using the next couple question/answer in the list ?

Comment: See the edited answer for a bare bones example of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things I found that you could fix:

1. This line blocks the UI (For details, see Jesper's answer):

   ```
   answer = MyQuestion(question).Result;
   ```

   If you change that to

   ```
   answer = await MyQuestion(question);
   ```

   it will work.
2. all your `if(question == qt)` blocks should be `else if`s so you don't just iterate all possible questions before the user gets the next question.

   Problem:

   ```
       question = qt1b;
   }
   if (question == qt1b)
   ```

   Solution:

   ```
   else if (question == qt1b)
   ```
3. you should check if the user pressed return in `answerTextBox_KeyPress` so answers can be longer than 1 character. Afterwards you should clear the TextBox for the next answer, e.g.:

   ```
   string result = answerTextBox.Text;
   answerTextBox.Text = "";
   return result;
   ```
4. You skip the first question because the call to `MyQuestion` is at the bottom of the loop, it should be at the top.